# Can a real harmonic function on the unit disk satisfy $f(0)=1$ while the area of $\{z:f(z)>0\}$ is zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Does there exist a harmonic function defined in the unit disk such that

(1) $f(0)=1$

(2) area of $\{z\in\mathbb{D}:\,f(z)>0\}$ is equal to zero?

---

I tried to use certain representations of harmonic functions, and to relate it to analytic content.

Comment: Tried to use certain representations , also tried to relate it to analytic content.

Comment: Note that since $f$ is harmonic it is continuous. What does that together with (1)$ tell you about the set in (2)?

Comment: That set is open.

Comment: What can you say about the area of an open set (which by (1)) is nonempty?

Comment: By regularity of Lesbegue measure ,area of that set has to be positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous and $f(0)=1$ then there exists $r>0$ such that the inequality $x^2 +y^2<r$ implies that $f(x,y)>\frac{1}{2} .$ Hence $$m(\{z\in\mathbb{D}: f(z)>0\} )>\pi r^2 >0,$$ 
where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: We dont know a priori such a function exists though.

Comment: @BigM: What FisiaiLusia probably means is: Suppose that $f$ is a real harmonic function on the disk such that $f(0)=1$.  Then for the reasons given above, it follows that for such an $f$, the area of the set where $f$ is positive is positive.  Hence, no real harmonic function satisfying (1) and (2) exists.

Comment: @JonasMeyer totally makes sense